# Seamless Video Sharing

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream, screensharing

I am trying to share the screen on a LAN, but it shows a very visible lag. I have tried several techniques but still lag is much visible. I tried the following techniques:

1. Sending frames on a socket from OutputStream
2. Compressing frames(jpeg) before sending using [aspose](https://downloads.aspose.com/imaging/java) library
3. Adding Frames to a Queue and then polling the queue for sending them

But Despite Trying all the methods, lag is still clearly visible. Can anyone share their opinion on how can I improve this much further so there is no/little lag while sharing screens on a LAN?

Sender.java

```
class SendScreen extends Thread{

    Socket socket=null;
    Robot robot=null;
    Rectangle rectangle=null;
    boolean continueLoop=true;
    Queue<BufferedImage> q;
  
    OutputStream oos=null;

    public SendScreen(Socket socket,Robot robot,Rectangle rect) {
    this.socket=socket;
    this.robot=robot;
    rectangle=rect;
        
        q= new LinkedList<>();
    start();
    }

    public void run(){
    
        try{
    oos=socket.getOutputStream(); 
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(continueLoop){
    BufferedImage image=robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);

    try{                                                      
             /* 
            ByteArrayOutputStream ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                
           ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", ous);

             InputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( ous.toByteArray() );

            Image original=Image.load(inStream);
    JpegOptions jpegOptions = new JpegOptions()
      {{
        // Apply compression
            setCompressionType(JpegCompressionMode.Progressive);
      }};
  
  // Save compressed image  
  ous.flush();*/ 
    q.add(image);
    //q.poll();
    ImageIO.write( q.poll(),"jpeg",oos);
//  original.save(oos);
            
            
            
        //ImageIO.write(image,"jpeg",oos);
    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    
    }
    }
}
```

Reciever.java

```
class ReceiveScreen extends Thread{
    private ObjectInputStream cObjectInputStream = null;
    private JPanel cPanel = null;
    private boolean continueLoop = true;
    InputStream oin = null;
    Image image1 = null;

    public ReceiveScreen(InputStream in,JPanel p){
        oin = in;
        cPanel = p;
        start();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            //Read screenshots of the client and then draw them
            while(continueLoop){
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024*1024];
                int count = 0;
                do{
                    count+=oin.read(bytes,count,bytes.length-count);
                }while(!(count>4 && bytes[count-2]==(byte)-1 && bytes[count-1]==(byte)-39));

                image1 = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                image1 = image1.getScaledInstance(cPanel.getWidth(),cPanel.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_FAST);

                //Draw the received screenshots

                Graphics graphics = cPanel.getGraphics();
                graphics.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, cPanel.getWidth(), cPanel.getHeight(), cPanel);
            }

        } catch(IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does using `BufferedOutputStream`/`BufferedInputStream` help? You could also consider UDP (datagram) sockets for faster connections.

Comment: Using BufferedOutputStream doesn't help. UDP Sockets doesn't allow sending anything >64KB and per frame size is actually bigger than that.

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't help? Doesn't it work or is it just not faster? The image compression/decompression might also be a bottleneck.

Comment: Image compression along with BufferedStreams improved the results somewhat but the lag was still very much visible.

Comment: You can try using tools to analyze things like CPU/network/memory consumption etc. (e.g. creating the screen capture could also be the problem). For example, you could use htop/task manager in order to see what kind of resources the application uses or tcptrack/wireshark to look at the packets (maybe the data is split up in multiple packets in an inefficient way) or use java specific monitoring tools for analyzing the performance in general.

Comment: If both the capture and the transmission are the problem, you could use multithreading in a way that the next screen is sent while the previous screen is recorded.

Comment: For testing, you could also try to use PipedOutputStream/PipedInputStream and run both sender and receiver in the same application in order to see if the network communication is the problem. If piped streams greatly improve the performance, it is likely a network problem but if that doesn't change much, the problem lies somewhere else.